# What is timestamp in VS modules debug window?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, timestamp

What is timestamp in VS modules debug window?

Is it 
Created timestamp?
Modified ?
Or signed timestamp

I changed the timestamps of a dll and still its showing something else not able to figure it out what exactly is it?

Answer (score 3):

The time stamp is part of the PE32 executable header. It's created by the linker. So you get a reliable information when the file was created.

The file dates (created, modified) may be changed by FTP or other copy operations.